# Java change label text from another frame

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a server/client program. In the server, when I click a button some infomations will be sent to client and show on a jLabel. But the problem is when the client get focus, it loses all the informations recieved. Somebody help me please!!!

Comment: It sounds like you've written a bug into your program.  Identifying it will require precise knowledge of the problem and likely access to all relevant source code.  The only advice we can really give you is that if the text in your JLabel is being erased, then somewhere in your code you're telling it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to perform the changes to JLabel on the EDT.